# Google Blogger: Instagram widget not working (access_token provided is invalid) using zeplin1.js

Tags: javascript, html, web, instagram, blogger

> Google Blogger: Instagram widget not working (access_token provided is invalid) using zeplin1.js.

Using Google's Blogger platform, I've trouble with the Instagram widget for pulling and displaying pictures.

Specifically, I receive the error "Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid".

How, do I fix this error from a highlevel point-of-view? Until now, I've dealt primarily with a CMS and have not written much low-level code.

Thanks for your time.